# Cant get Asset2SD to work..:-/

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins

I've been trying to have cordova plugins working for weeks now. Can't seem to have a simple one like Asset2SD workinf either.

Here is what I do (step by step)

I get the plugin via the CLI

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/gkcgautam/Asset2SD.git
```

Then I add the name of the plugin to my confi.xml like so:

```
   <plugin name="asset2sd.copyFile" />
```

Then I wrote this snipet that gets a uri of a clicked pdf file that should then be sent to sd card:

```
$('a[href$=\\.pdf]').click(function() {
    var myuri = this.href ;

    alert(myuri); 
    alert(this.href);
    /* storing and opening the file */            
    asset2sd.copyFile(
       {
          asset_file: this.href,
          destination_file: "Download/new.pdf"
       },
       function() { alert('success'); }, 
       function() { alert('fail'); }
    );               
})
```

Nothing happens, except the first two alerts, that do give me the file's full path from the asset folder.

I don't even get the "**fail**" alert from the plugin.

I then tried to hardcode the "variable" to see if something was wrong with giving the full path (the example in github only gives a "www/... "path

```
$('a[href$=\\.pdf]').click(function() {
    var myuri = this.href ;

    alert(myuri); 
    alert(this.href);

    /* storing and opening the file */                    
    asset2sd.copyFile(
        {
            asset_file: "wwww/res/DOC140416-1.pdf",
            destination_file: "Download/newdoc.pdf"
        },
        function() { alert('success'); }, 
        function() { alert('fail'); }
    );                   
})
```

Nothing changed either.

Any help apreciated!!!

Comment: The problem could be, that you are using a very old plugin which is not  compatible with the current cordova version.

Comment: Thanks!
Did not know Cordova made older plugins obsolete! Worth knowing about. Is there anyway to know what is current or not? 
Cheers